# androidx.spinner onItemSelectedListener not working

Tags: androidx

**Am trying to use a spinner in a layout. I can add and select items to the spinner but I cannot retrieve the selected item. This is the main activity:**

```
class pageNewPurchaseOrder : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var spinnerVendorX: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    var spinnerArray: java.util.ArrayList<CharSequence> = ArrayList<CharSequence>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_new_purchase_order)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
     spinnerVendorX = findViewById(R.id.spinnerVendorX)
      spinnerVendorX.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this@pageNewPurchaseOrder, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray)
        spinnerVendorX.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Log.d("aaa", "This code is not running!")

            }

        }

    }
}
```

This is the layout activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".pageNewPurchaseOrder"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_page_new_purchase_order">

         <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bgselect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl2"
            android:id="@+id/spinnerVendorX" />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Am getting result this on the logcat when I select an item: `E/ViewRootImpl(31835): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null`.I get tj=he same results even when I use `<Spinner` instead of `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner`

Answer (score 1):

User must have to add data in the ArrayList. Here, you are initialising arrayList and set it but not adding data in ArrayList. Please add data in ArrayList then try it. Thank you.